# Why does Google Chrome take so long to refresh local files? Anyway to improve?

Tags: google-chrome

I am developing a simple HTML/CSS only site locally.

Annoyingly (and weirdly) Chrome is taking ages to refresh the page after I make changes - around 5 - 7 secs.

Computer is fine, as is internet connection. Sites online load normally.

Would anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix it (if possible)?

Thanks!

(Running Chrome 30.0.1599.69)

Comment: This is a problem with the local server like IIS.. which local server you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it was because I was linking out to Googles hosted JQuery library. It doesnt like loading that from local for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, just wanted to let you know what fixed it for me.

If you're hosting locally, your code may look something like this:

`src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"`

Add in the `http:` to the `src` attribute or chrome is going to look for the jQuery library locally.

`src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"`

Comment: For me, it wasn't jQuery, but another library.  But in my case, changing src="//..." to src="http://..." completely worked.

Answer (score 0):

After months, I finally found the solution to this problem on my case. The following html tag was making it very slow on Chrome and IE, but not Firefox (locally):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Since I'm not that worried about compatibility I just removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I have been noticed this bug for quite a while.

It seems to be stuck at loading certain local resources for no reason (and it would *eventually* load, albeit took 10+ seconds):

[image: show slow loading]

And during the whole time, nothing is rendered on the page (totally blank).

- It does not happen with Firefox.
- It does not happen if you simply host it on any localhost server.

The weird thing about this bug is that it isn't caused by any single resource or html element; once you reduced the elements on the HTML to a degree, it will suddenly start to work.

That's why the above answers were able to "fix" it by randomly remove something.

If you try to reduce an HTML file to find a minimum reproducible example, you will realize there are multiple ways to make it work (mostly by removing some JS, but sometimes removing some  tag would also do the trick); there is no single culprit.

I personally think it's some part of the rendering process of Chrome doesn't work well with file:// protocol (probably due to lack of testing) and it's not exposed to dev tool well to tell/debug.

I have reported it on [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1050294) but sadly no response yet.

Comment: In case of the accepted answer it was likely because of the same thing the most upvoted answer mentions: it was using `//` to automatically pick between `http://` and `https://` schemes, but the file was being opened with the `file://` scheme.

Comment: @gronostaj: if you check the sample HTML file I provided in the bug report page, there is only one `//` is used in that HTML, and changing it to absolute `https://` or simply removing that <script> entirely doesn't fix the slow loading problem. So no, I don't think that's the (only) cause.

Comment: Also, the problem is more about: why it doesn't render the page at all even if some resource loading is stuck. It doesn't happen if you host the file with any static server (like Python http.server); it doesn't happen at all on Firefox. So I would still consider it a bug even if you can work around it. I expanded the answer above to make it more clear.

Comment: I wasn't referring to your example, but to original poster's experience. [Removing jQuery worked for them](https://superuser.com/a/656430/194694) and my suspicion is that [they had it included using the `//` "scheme"](https://superuser.com/a/923120/194694). I'm not saying the bug doesn't exist - it seems to be verified according to your report - but that it's not what may have been causing OP's problem.